# Opening terminal links with the keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, url, xfce4-terminal

One of the very useful things about `urxvt` is that I could use keyboard shortcuts to navigate through and open hyperlinks that appeared on the terminal screen (by adding some `urxvt*` entries on `.Xresources`, IIRC).

Now I'm on `xfce4-terminal` and am missing this functionality. I took a look at `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` but couldn't find anything relevant. For the moment, I'm stuck to having to grab my mouse and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click the terminal URLs I want to open in the browser, which is quite disruptive to my workflow.

Question: **is it possible to select and open URLs printed on the xfce4-terminal just using the keyboard?**

I'd be glad to hear about other terminal emulators that offer this functionality, but I don't intend on going back to urxvt for the moment.

Comment: You can use `Ctrl+Shift+F` search by for example regex Esc, then copy by `Ctrl+Shift+C` ... not ideal and I know I have seen something about this elsewhere, but can not find it. Thought it was here https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal - but does not look like it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @ibuprofen. This doesn't seem to work for long URLs spanning multiple lines, but it's definitely a step forward. I'll expand on this a bit as an answer as I wait for a more proper solution.

Comment: Yes. It is not a good solution. I use `xfcef-terminal` as well, (though a custom build). I have still not managed to locate where I read about the hyperlink collection. The botched highlighting is a (bug) I believe in vte (xfce uses vte). Actually if one search forward entire match is highlighted, but not when searching backwards (or on initial search). One can ofc use `screen` etc., but that is not a solution either.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on @ibuprofen's answer, here's a workaround that works as long as the URL doesn't span multiple lines:

1. Open <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Enable searching with regular expressions
3. Enter `http\S+` as the search term
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> until the desired URL is highlighted
5. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the URL to the clipboard
7. Paste it on your browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (you might need to press something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> first to focus the address bar)

Comment: You could use - look at `menu -> Terminal -> Fin next / previous`. If not bound to any key you can change `./config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` (I use Ctrl+ and Ctrl- as I do not zoom anyway). *Then* after you have set search string you can search forward. When searching *forward* text that wraps is highlighted as well. Then - next time you want to search you do not need `Ctrl+Shift+F` if it is in same terminal window. Just do previous / next - and it searches using set pattern. Unfortunately it does not look like there is a way to make it save patterns between launches (as of now).

Comment: nor setting regex as toggled. Had a look at this https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-terminal/blob/6bac5f5a69229b48c90547acf227e508b971723c/terminal/terminal-search-dialog.c#L148 etc. There are some custom MISC options one can set, and it would be easy enough to write a patch, but then one would need a custom build.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any terminal running Bash on Linux, BSD, or macOS. [(video demo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6Wee8o4x1s)

Note: It only opens the last link, but it could definitely be extended to select interactively.

```bash
# Add this somewhere in your .bashrc

# Record terminal to this file.
__terminal_recording_file="${HOME}/.cache/terminal_recording"

function __start_recording_terminal () {
  # if the file exists, don't record, as this means that the recording is
  # already happening in the current shell.
  if [[ -f "$__terminal_recording_file" ]]; then
    return
  fi

  # save the PID of the shell that started the recording
  echo $$ >| "$__terminal_recording_file.pid"

  # Start recording, with "flushing" option to have quick access to the last
  # output, and quiet option to disable "started recording" message.
  # Also, check if script can be run with '-f' (linux) or '-F' (macOS)
  script -q -f /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
  local script_can_be_run_with_f="$?"
  if [[ "$script_can_be_run_with_f" -ne 0 ]]; then
    script -q -F "$__terminal_recording_file"
  else
    script -q -f "$__terminal_recording_file"
  fi
}
start_recording_terminal # comment this line to disable recording

function __open_last_visible_link_in_terminal () {
  # look for the last thing that looks like a link in the last 50 lines of the
  # terminal recording (assumed to be the currently visible part of the
  # terminal)
  local link="$( tail -n 50 "$__terminal_recording_file" | tac | grep -Eo -m 1 --color=never 'https?://[[:print:]]+')"
  if [[ -z "$link" ]]; then
    echo "No link found"
    return 1
  fi

  echo "Opening link: $link"
  open "$link"
}

# Bind Ctrl-K to "__open_last_visible_link_in_terminal" in all modes
# Also, it runs Ctrl-u first, so that the command line is cleared and it
# doesn't interfere.
bind -m emacs     '"\C-k":"\C-u __open_last_visible_link_in_terminal\n"'
bind -m vi-insert '"\C-k":"\C-u __open_last_visible_link_in_terminal\n"'
bind -m vi        '"\C-k":"\C-u __open_last_visible_link_in_terminal\n"'

# cleanup function on Bash exit
function __cleanup () {
  # if a recording is happening and the parent of this shell is the recording
  # command, kill the shell that started the recording and remove the files
  ps -p $PPID | grep -q 'script -q'
  is_parent_script="$?"
  if [[ -f "$__terminal_recording_file" && "$is_parent_script" -eq 0 ]]; then
    rm "$__terminal_recording_file"

    # kill the shell that started the recording
    local pid="$(cat "$__terminal_recording_file.pid")"
    rm "$__terminal_recording_file.pid"
    kill -9 "$pid"
  fi
}
trap __cleanup EXIT
```

Btw Alacritty has that as a built-in feature: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Alacritty#Regex_hints

It can also be done in tmux with the [tmux-urlview](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-urlview) plugin.